# Retrieve data from Wordpress custom table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Hi im trying to echo single data from a custom table inside my wordpress database.
I found [the code to print multiple columns](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51984/how-to-display-data-from-custom-table-in-wordpress-database). However I just want to print a single field, so my code looks like this:

```
global $wpdb;
echo $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM table.column WHERE id = 1" );
```

Unfortunately it just prints the word 'Array'

Comment: Don't echo out the results of your query. Store them in a variable and then use it later on...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
global $wpdb;
echo $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM table.column WHERE id = 1" );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an array and trying to echo it.

**SELECT a Variable**

The `get_var` function returns a single variable from the database. Though only one variable is returned, the entire result of the query is cached for later use. Returns NULL if no result is found.

```
<?php $wpdb->get_var( 'query', column_offset, row_offset ); ?>
```

**SELECT a Row**

To retrieve an entire row from a query, use `get_row`. The function can return the row as an object, an associative array, or as a numerically indexed array. If more than one row is returned by the query, only the specified row is returned by the function, but all rows are cached for later use. Returns NULL if no result is found, consider this when using the returned value in arguments, see example below.

```
<?php $wpdb->get_row('query', output_type, row_offset); ?>
```

check this [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Answer (score 1):

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM table.column WHERE id = 1" );

foreach ($result as $post){
echo $id = $post->columnName1;
echo $id = $post->columnName2;
echo $id = $post->columnName3;
}
```

> or

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM table.column WHERE id = 1" );

foreach ($result as $post){
$colm1 = $post->columnName1;
$colm2 = $post->columnName2;
$colm3 = $post->columnName3;

echo '<p>'. $colm1 . '</p>'
echo '<p>'. $colm2 . '</p>'
echo '<p>'. $colm3 . '</p>'
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

$mylink = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->links WHERE link_id = 10" );

OR

$wpdb->get_var( 'query', column_offset, row_offset );

for go there https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb