# WordPress get value from postmeta by post id

Tags: php, wordpress

I have WordPress website and I want to get meta_value (7) from ej_postmeta table where post_id = 200
Also table postmeta has prefix ej_  and I want to show result in header.php.

Database structure

meta_id | post_id | meta_key        | meta_value

100     | 200     | new_job_posted  | 7

So I use get_post_meta function in header.php

I try ( header.php )

```
 global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->show_errors();
    $values = get_post_meta( 200, 'meta_value' );
    echo $values;

and


global $wpdb;
$wpdb->show_errors();
$myvals = get_post_meta(200);
    
foreach($myvals as $key=>$val)
{
  echo $key . ' : ' . $val[0] . '<br/>';
}
```

But I get nothing

Comment: I think it's better to ask this question on: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/
Also, this sounds like a custom table. I think you'll need to use the get_results function for this. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626775/retrieve-data-from-wordpress-custom-table-using-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter should be the meta key name.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

This line

```
$values = get_post_meta( 200, 'meta_value' );
```

should be

```
$values = get_post_meta( 200, 'new_job_posted' );
```

Comment: $values = get_post_meta( 200, 'new_job_posted' );
echo $values; Warning: Array to string conversion and no results

Comment: replace echo with print_r().

Comment: print_r($values); no results

Comment: all code global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->show_errors();
        $values = get_post_meta( 200, 'new_job_posted' );
        print_r($values); but no results

Comment: then double check the post id and the meta key in DB. maybe there is an underscore prefix? anyway this is the right way to get the meta value.

Comment: No underscore prefix. This code in header.php Maybe problem with database? I add $wpdb

Comment: maybe. is this prefix 'ej_' for postmeta table only? It should be the same for all tables and the variable $table_prefix = 'ej_'; should be set in wp-config.php

Comment: yes $table_prefix = 'ej_'; in wp-config file. All tables have ej_ prefix

Comment: sry, don't know. It could be a plugin messing with the meta return values.